# How to convert a non-UTF-8 encoding to a more readable/ UTF-8 encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I am using 'PDF Parser' in a Laravel 5.4 project to get the contents of a pdf file. But when I dump the contents, I get some encoded text which when hovered upon, reads '5868 binary or non-UTF-8 characters'.

This is the code that is supposed to read the file's contents.

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile($file);
$scannedText = $pdf->getText();
dd($scannedText);
```

which dumps something like this:

```
x00i\x00n\x00g\x00ª\x00t\x00h\x00i
```

The PHP's `mb_detect_encoding()` function returns false when the "encoding type" is set to "auto". 
`utf8_encode()` doesn't work either, so I know it's not an ISO-8859-1 encoding.

This is where I'm stuck now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get the raw bytes into a hex/text editor and select different encodings for it to interpret the content in, until you find an encoding in which the text looks correct. If every other byte is `00`, you may be looking at UTF-16 encoded text.

Comment: Tricky this. You can't convert the encoding until you know what the original encoding is. I would look to see if I can extract the encoding information from the original PDF file itself. Possibly the abstraction library you are using, ``Smalot\PdfParser\Parser``, might be able to provide this information? If not you'll need to look at other PDF parsing solutions. It's an interesting problem - do keep us posted on your eventual solution! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, fellas. 
@kieranpotts  I checked the pdf file and the fonts are in Identity-H encoding. Also, when I use Laravel's built-in File System to retrieve the contents (instead of the PdfParser package), and then dump the contents, some unreadable text is shown, but the encoding seems different now. So I go ahead and do a `mb_detect_encoding` and I get 'UTF - 8'. This time, I believe the problem lies in trying to dump the file contents. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @deceze that's a nice thought. But I'm looking for a simpler, programmatic solution that I can code. Thanks though...Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I got similar error with 'PDF Parser'.

But I didn't have this error anymore using : https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text.

You can use composer to install it :

```
composer require spatie/pdf-to-text
```

And it works like that :

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;

$pdf = (new Pdf())->setPdf('sample.pdf');

$pdf->setOptions(['layout']);

dump($pdf->text());
```

Comment: I was working on this project around a year ago and I remember after struggling for a while with PDF Parser, I switched to PdfToText, and it worked like a charm. Forgot to post it here though. Anyway, thank you for your response.Cheers!